# How To point to an object from string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My question is kind of general; in my project I have 10 `UIButton` objects
named Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6, Button7, Button8, Button9,  and Button10

I also have `UIImageview` That are named exactly like the buttons from 1 to 10.

I want to write a code that will manipulate the image by the last character of the button (always a number from 1 to 10) and will affect the `UIImageview` the same way

Something like this

```
buttonlastcharacter = i;
    if(sender.lastcharacternumber is:i){
    Button%,i.frame = //Some manipulation
```

But basically all that I want is to have access to a certain object by string

How can I implement such a behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is maybe not the ideal solution in your case, but you can do it different ways:

using kvo

```
UIButton* myButton = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"button%i",i]];
```

or with selectors and properties

```
UIButton* myButton = [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"button%i",i])];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of better ways to do this.  If these buttons are all static and in IB you can use an IBCollection array for image views and buttons to simply call them up by matching indexes.

Better yet just use the tag value for the buttons or image views.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,
In your IBAction method:

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
 UIButton *but = (UIButton *)sender;
 but.frame = your manipulation code;
}
```

or you can check the title like:

```
if([but.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Button1])
{
 //Manipulate button 1
}
```

if you have added tags for the buttons from 1-10 you can use,

```
if(but.tag == 2)
{
   //Manipulate button 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm, you could use an array for your buttons and a tag for your UIImageView objects. They all inherit from UIView, which provides you with a .tag propterty. It is of type NSInteger* .

For convenience reasons I would suggest to name the buttons from 0 to 9. It does not really matter but the first index in the array would be 0 and therefore naming them accordingly just makes things easier.

Define

```
NSArray *buttonArray;
```

You may opt for NSMutableArray depending what else you may want to do with it.

In viewDidLoad code:

```
buttonArray = [NSArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
buttonArray[0] = button0;
..
buttonArray[9] = button9;
```

In your XIB file in Interface Builder, or whereever you may create the UIImages programmatically, add the tags accordingly.

```
image0.tag = 0; 
...
image0.tag = 9;
```

assuming you name them image0 to image9.

In your appropriate action method code:

```
buttonArray[sender.tag] = someManipulation;
```